# an error when i try deploy ADF project with dependencies

Tags: azure-data-factory

When I try to deploy ADF project from visual studio to azure, I get the error:

```
21.02.2017 13:03:32- Publishing Project 'MyProj.DataFactory'....
21.02.2017 13:03:32- Validating 10 json files
21.02.2017 13:03:37- Publishing Project 'MyProj.DataFactory' to Data Factory 'MyProjDataFactory'
21.02.2017 13:03:37- Starting upload of Dependency D:\Sources\MyProjDataFactory\Dependencies\ParseMyData.usql
```

The dependency is Azure Data Lake Analytics U-SQL script.

Where are the dependencies stored in azure?

**UPDATE:**

When i try to orchestrate a U-SQL stored proc instead of script the visual studio validator trows me the error on build:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

1) Store the USQL file in Azure Blob Storage. In which case you'll need a linked service in your Azure Data Factory to blobs. Then upload the file manually or add the file to your Visual Studio project dependencies for data factory. Unfortunately this will mean the USQL becomes static in the ADF project and not linked in any way to your ADL project so be careful.

2) The simplest way is just to in line the USQL code directly in the ADF JSON. Again is means you'll need to manually refresh code from the ADL project.

3) **My preferred approach**... Create the USQL as a stored procedure in the Azure Data Lake Analytics service. Then reference the proc in the JSON using [database].[schema].[procname]. You can also pass parameters to the proc from ADF. For example the time slice. This also assumes you already have ADL setup as a linked service in ADF.

Hope this helps.

I have a blog post about the 3rd options and passing params here if your interested: http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/02/passing-parameters-to-u-sql-from-azure-data-factory/

Thanks

Comment: thank you. I like third solution. And this is what i'm going to use. But just for clarity. Could you explain little bit more about the first option. If i add the U-SQL script as a dependency in VS's project for ADF and try to deploy this project to the Azure, i get an error about access rights, where does it try to store the dependencies? And wich rights i should have to deploy the project with dependencies (it is deployed successfully without the dependencies). Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. Good point. In the JSON activity you need to use the attribute "scriptLinkedService", referring to some blob storage linked service. This tells ADF where to upload the script file from your dependencies. Next, in the portal, go to your ADL analytics services and add blob storage as a data sources. As well as the ADL storage. This gives it the access it needs to run the USQL file. Your up votes and marking the above as your question answer would be appreciated.

Comment: could you please help me? I added a screenshot to my first post where my current problem is shown. I'm trying to invoke the stored proc from ADF and i use the ADF's visual studio project. But the visual studio throws me an error when i try to build the solution: Reference [mydb][my_schema].[myproc] is not declared in the solution. How to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: looks like i fixed it, i accidentaly use scriptPath instead of script. :) thanx for your blog.

Comment: Happy to help :-)